# Ubuntu 14.04 microphone static ASUS Q502LA

Tags: 14.04, alsa, microphone

I tried following the procedures here without any luck:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure

Here is the output of system description.

http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=b20f729d6081bde9d14f9269217296c3196392f5

Any help would be appreciated.